# Moving From one widget to another PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have designed the widgets in PyQT designer. This are frameless widgets with custom size and templates. I am using two different widgets that run one after another for login into my Main application. The First widget is WelcomeScreenWidget wherein user clicks 'ENTER' button leading to second widget called LoginScreenWidget where user puts login information and presses 'LOGIN' button leading to MainApplicationScreen. I tried using QStackedLayout but it needs to resize my widget removing the design and customization. Below is my main code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from WelcomeWidget import WelcomeUi_Form
from LoginWidget import LoginUi_Form

class AppWelcome(QtWidgets.QWidget,WelcomeUi_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWelcome,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class AppLogin(QtWidgets.QWidget,LoginUi_Form):
   def __init__(self):
        super(AppLogin,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = AppWelcome()
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So the way I want the Flow be is:
WelcomeWidget(AppWelcome)->LoginWidget(AppLogin)
I want to keep my design because using QStackedWidget shows the title bar with with all our regular options which my widgets have inbuilt. Any work around that. Also attaching one of the widget pictures for reference so know what I'm talking about.
How will I do it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code can help you:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from WelcomeWidget import WelcomeUi_Form
# from LoginWidget import LoginUi_Form

class AppWelcome(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWelcome,self).__init__()
        # self.setupUi(self)
        self.enter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Enter", self)
        self.lbl_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("AppWelcome", self)

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.lbl_1)
        v_box.addWidget(self.enter_button)
        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.enter_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_login)

    def go_to_login(self):
        Form.setCurrentIndex(Form.currentIndex()+1)

class AppLogin(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppLogin,self).__init__()
        # self.setupUi(self)
        self.login_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Login", self)

        self.lbl_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("AppLogin", self)

        v_box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box2.addWidget(self.lbl_2)
        v_box2.addWidget(self.login_button)
        self.setLayout(v_box2)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_main)

    def go_to_main(self):
        Form.setCurrentIndex(Form.currentIndex()+1)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.setupUi(self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        widget.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: none"
        )
        
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("MainWindow", self)
        v_box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box3.addWidget(self.lbl_3)
        self.setLayout(v_box3)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    welcome_window = AppWelcome()
    app_login_window = AppLogin()
    main_window = MainWindow()
    Form.addWidget(welcome_window)
    Form.addWidget(app_login_window)
    Form.addWidget(main_window)
    Form.setFixedSize(400, 600)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

If your forms have different sizes then you didn't need QStackWidget, so you can use this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
# from WelcomeWidget import WelcomeUi_Form
# from LoginWidget import LoginUi_Form

class AppWelcome(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWelcome,self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(100, 600)
        # self.setupUi(self)
        self.enter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Enter", self)
        self.lbl_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("AppWelcome", self)

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.lbl_1)
        v_box.addWidget(self.enter_button)
        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.enter_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_login)

    def go_to_login(self):
        # Form.setCurrentIndex(Form.currentIndex()+1)
        welcome_window.close()
        app_login_window.show()

class AppLogin(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppLogin,self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        # self.setupUi(self)
        self.login_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Login", self)

        self.lbl_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("AppLogin", self)

        v_box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box2.addWidget(self.lbl_2)
        v_box2.addWidget(self.login_button)
        self.setLayout(v_box2)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.go_to_main)

    def go_to_main(self):
        # Form.setCurrentIndex(Form.currentIndex()+1)
        app_login_window.close()
        main_window.show()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(700, 700)
        # self.setupUi(self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        widget.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: none"
        )
        
        self.initUI()
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("MainWindow", self)
        v_box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box3.addWidget(self.lbl_3)
        self.setLayout(v_box3)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    welcome_window = AppWelcome()
    app_login_window = AppLogin()
    main_window = MainWindow()
    welcome_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: No layout can be set on a QMainWindow. You need to set a central widget and set the layout for it.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarification but is there anyway to do it for different widget size because each widget like AppWelcome, Applogin and Main Window are different custom sizes. So is there way to change the size based on widget and I am not using the titlebar because I have used custom inbuilt options for that.

Comment: I have updated the code that make simply using fixed sizes of any of your forms.